# How do i run Fluent Migrator within visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, fluent-migrator

I created a Migration in visual studio I added Fluent Migrator to my project with Nuget, but how do I run the migration to add the tables and columns to my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, we install the `Fluent Migrator Tools` nuget package inside our
   Migrations project. This will download and extract a `Migrate.exe`
   executable. This executable can be used to execute your migrations
   from the command line, exactly what we need
2. Add the `Migrate.exe` and the `FluentMigrator.Runner.dll` assemblies to
   your project by right-clicking on the project and selecting Add an
   existing item. Navigate to the packages folder of your solution and
   pick the Migrate.exe and the `FluentMigrator.Runner.dll` that are
   somewhere inside the FluentMigrator.Tools folder. Make sure you
   select Add as link
3. Open up the properties for the `Migrate.exe` and
   `FluentMigrator.Runner.dll` items in your Visual Studio project, and
   set it to Copy to output directory: Copy always
4. Our project is now in the perfect shape to make an external tool
   consume it. Open up the external tools manager and create a new
   tool. Give it the following values.

```
Title: FluentMigrate
Command: $(BinDir)\Migrate.exe
Arguments: --provider sqlserver2008 --a $(TargetName)$(TargetExt)
Initial Directory: $(BinDir)
Use output window: click checkbox
```

[More Info](http://thomasvm.github.io/blog/2012/12/10/launch-fluentmigrator-from-within-visual-studio/)